# XStream and scientific notation issue

Tags: java, xstream

I have an object that I convert to XML using XStream.  Occasionally I am encountering errors (not all the time) on fields that are both of type Integer and double.  I get the java error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".12625E312625"` because XStream seems to be converting this number to scientific notation.  I cannot figure out how this is occurring and how I should correct it.  I could see if the double numbers were very large but my numbers never exceed 100,000.00 and I don't understand why it would be doing it on the Integer field.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I've never seen XStream convert an integer to exponential notation. Are you sure you've got the same classes on the marshalling and unmarshalling side? I suspect a field is type `double` in one case and `int` in another.